# iOS device-height viewport too long

Tags: html, ios, safari, height, viewport

I currently have the following viewport for my webapp:

```
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```

The problem with using height=device-height is that it is taking in account the entire screens height. I need device-height minus the browser GUI. As it stands, the page is about 40-50px too long. I don't want to hardcode the css to be subtracted by that amount since the GUI could be changed depending on the browser, accessibility settings, etc... Anybody have a solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Used a combination of answers I found in threads here

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad;.*CPU.*OS 7_\d/i) && window.innerHeight != document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
       var fixViewportHeight = function () {
           document.documentElement.style.height = inner + "px";
           if ($("input,textarea,select").is(":focus")) {
                 $('body').css('position', 'static');
           }
           else {
              $('body').css('position', 'fixed');
           }
       };
       window.addEventListener("scroll", fixViewportHeight, false);
       window.addEventListener("orientationchange", fixViewportHeight, false);
       fixViewportHeight();
       document.body.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(0,0,0)";
    }
```

Comment: `inner` is not defined. Also, could you post your sources ?

Answer (score 0):

Correct, the viewport is your complete device, including GUI.

The most simple solution; just don't set the height! Use the browsers `height: 100%` on `html, body` to get the desired absolute height.